# JavaScript Identify Status For Months Starting Later

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array of objects with months and status properties:

```
const data = [
  {
    "month": "Jan",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Feb",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Mar",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Apr",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "May",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Jun",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Jul",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Aug",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Sep",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Oct",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Nov",
    "status": "Full"
  },
  {
    "month": "Dec",
    "status": "Full"
  },
]
```

Basically I would like to know if all of the statuses for each month is "Full". Using every function:

```
const status = data.every(d => d.status === 'Full');
```

I'm able to know if all of the months have "Full" statuses. However, I would also like to identify if the month is started at a later date e.g. on April to December, then it would still return true. What would be the best logic for achieving this? What I've tried so far:

```
function identifyStatus(data) {
  const status = data.every(d => d.status === 'Full') && data.length;
  let finalStatus = false;
  
    if (!status) {
    let start = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (start !== -1) {
        if (data[i].status === 'Full' && i !== data.length - 1) {
          continue;
        } else {
            finalStatus = true;
        }
      } else {
        if (data[i].status === 'Full') {
          start = i;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return finalStatus;
}
```

Need inputs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to return true if say, January and February are not "Full" but every subsequent month is "Full".

To do that, I would first find the index where the first "Full" appears, using Array.findIndex.

```js
const firstMonth = data.findIndex(d => d.status === "Full")
```

Then, if a match exists, create an array slice to iterate over with the `every` function.

```js
if (firstMonth >= 0) { // findIndex returns -1 in case of no match
  const fullMonths = data.slice(firstMonth)
  return fullMonths.every(d => d.status === "Full")
}
```

Comment: Yes every subsequent month is "Full". Thanks for this, great!